# Prevent a systemd service from starting if another systemd service is running

Tags: systemd, job-control, systemd-service

In systemd (v237 on UbuntuLinux 18.04 bionic), I can create a service file (for `A.service`), and specify another service `Requisite=B.service`. Meaning if I try to start `A.service` and `B.service` isn't already running, then A.service will not be started. It's a weak version of `Requires`, which will start `B.service` when I try to start `A.service`.

Is there an opposite? Can I say “If B.service is running, then *don't* start this service” / “If B.service is running, then A.service cannot start”?

The docs say if I do `Conflicts=B.service`, then starting `A` will stop B and then start A. But I don't want B stopped, I just want A to fail to start. I want something that's to `Conflicts` what `Requisite` is to `Requires`.

I could probably change the `ExecStart` to be a shell command that'll fail is `systemctl is-active B.service` or some sort of hack. Is there a proper solution?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that, except writing a script. Did you see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503719/how-to-set-a-conflict-in-systemd-in-one-direction-only ?

Answer (score 6):

Generally the way to do this is with an `ExecStartPre` that checks whether the other services is running.  If an `ExecStartPre` command returns an error code then the rest of the startup process is aborted.

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c '! /usr/bin/systemctl is-active --quiet other-unit.service'
```

Comment: just need to mention that is-active will check for active services that is not the same thing as running; if the tested unit is active, it will exit 1; that will lead to a unit starting fail

Answer (score 6):

Something I found later, the best option for this situation is `ExecCondition=` because it will allow you do do a proper error control; `ExecStartPre=` will always generate an error if exits with non-zero; while `ExecCondition=` will permits to halt the execution without throwing an error, or trowing an error if required. This will be very handy for notifications on `ExecStartPost=` processing (you can set a trigger to notify that the service did not start because the other was running).

> ExecCondition=
> Optional commands that are executed before the command(s) in
> ExecStartPre=. Syntax is the same as for ExecStart=, except
> that multiple command lines are allowed and the commands are
> executed one after the other, serially.
>
> The behavior is like an ExecStartPre= and condition check
> hybrid: when an ExecCondition= command exits with exit code 1
> through 254 (inclusive), the remaining commands are skipped
> and the unit is not marked as failed. However, if an
> ExecCondition= command exits with 255 or abnormally (e.g.
> timeout, killed by a signal, etc.), the unit will be
> considered failed (and remaining commands will be skipped).
> Exit code of 0 or those matching SuccessExitStatus= will
> continue execution to the next command(s).
>
> The same recommendations about not running long-running
> processes in ExecStartPre= also applies to ExecCondition=.
> ExecCondition= will also run the commands in ExecStopPost=,
> as part of stopping the service, in the case of any non-zero
> or abnormal exits, like the ones described above.

The code logic is the same:

```
ExecCondition=/bin/bash -xc '/usr/bin/systemctl is-active --quiet other-unit.service && { [[ %i == "main" ]] && exit 255 || exit 1; } || exit 0'
```

The advantage of `ExecCondition=` over `ExecStartPre=`, is that in this example, it will check if this service instance is the "main" and will exit with a failed status code, so you can easily notice it; also you can use as a trigger for `ExecStartPost=` and `ExecStopPost=`.

One recommendation is to use many entries of `ExecCondition=` instead running too many commands in a single entry despite permitted; it will enhance troubleshooting and prevent failed state due timeout.

Comment: What does the `%i` in that code do?

Comment: if the service that you are testing have instances, %i, will be translated to the instance name so, the condition will operate only for a specific instance http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/systemd.unit.html