# Verify in ExecStartPre if bash binary exists

Tags: systemd, job-control, systemd-service

I want my service to start only if another service is not active. To do so, as explained in [this other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1016586/prevent-a-systemd-service-from-starting-if-another-systemd-service-is-running), I am going to do:

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -xc '/usr/bin/systemctl is-active --quiet other-unit.service && exit 1 || exit 0'
```

However, there is a small possibility that the OS does not include /bin/bash. In that case, I'd like the service to start anyway. I was trying to achieve this by using:

```
ExecStartPre=which bash 2>/dev/null && /usr/bin/bash -xc '/usr/bin/systemctl is-enabled --quiet nm-cloud-setup.service && exit 1 || exit 0' || exit 0
```

But systemd complains:

```
which[1122772]: /usr/bin/which: invalid option -- 'x'
which[1122772]: /usr/bin/which: invalid option -- 'c'
which[1122772]: /usr/bin/which: no && in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
```

I guess ExecStartPre= is quite limited. Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: Why are you calling bash instead of /bin/sh?

Comment: I pasted what the other question answered. If I change to /usr/bin/sh, can I be sure that it will be part of all OS?

Comment: I said `/bin/sh`, not `/usr/bin/sh`. The former exists on literally everything vaguely Unix-like for the last 50 years. It's even on your phone. I said nothing about the latter and would not count on it.

Comment: ok. In that case, I don't need to check if `/bin/sh` is available, thanks. Could you write that as an answer so that I can mark the question as answered please?

Comment: OK. But just for curiosity I would like to know what system includes systemd but not bash.

Comment: I just wanted to cover all possible cases. I have seen one an Alpine OS using systemd because the user installed it somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than calling bash, you should consider calling the Bourne shell `/bin/sh` which has been around pretty much since the beginning of Unix and exists on literally everything Unix-like, all the way down to your phone. (Though on modern systems it is generally substituted with a slightly more capable shell that runs in Bourne shell compatibility mode when called as `/bin/sh`.)